# Extending a wireless network with an Airport Express

Tags: wifi, airport

I have a wireless network based on a Time Capsule (802.11n, first generation). As wireless connectivity is rather bad in one part of the house I wanted to use an Airport Express (802.11g) to extend the network. The end result should look somehow like

```
Internet Router <--LAN--> Time Capsule <--WiFi--> Airport Express
```

with the Time Capsule and the Airport Express both running in the same WiFi network.

Based on the documentation I found (e.g. [HT4262](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4262)) I assume I should create a WDS network but this somehow doesn't seem to work (the Express disappears from Airport Utility as soon as I define it as a WDS relay/remote base station).

So how do I have to configure the network in both the Time Capsule and the Airport Express to get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the automatic configuration for the Express?

Don't do anything on the Time Capsule.

Do a cold reset of the express and bring it up on the Airport Utility.  You should have an option to join an existing Airport network. Choose the option to extend the range. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to set up a WDS, but rather to use the Airport Express in "client mode."

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1731

Comment: From HT2272: "In client mode, AirPort Express does not offer itself as a wireless access point or use its Ethernet port." :-(

Answer (score 1):

you cant extend the 802.11n network because the express operates on 'g' wireless. only way is to set up WDS, but thats compromising to your bandwidth and not a good idea. sorry. I had the same issue. its annoying, but oh well.